# Checking if a key exists and its value is not an empty string in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, string

Is there a clear best practice for assigning a variable from a key/value pair in a Python dictionary:

- If the key is present
- If the key's value is not an empty string

And otherwise assigning a default value to the variable.

I would like to use `dict.get`:

```
my_value = dict.get(key, my_default)
```

But this assigns an empty string to `my_value` if the key is present and the value is an empty string. Is it better to use the following:

```
if key in dict and dict[key]:
    my_value = dict[key]
else:
    my_value = my_default
```

This would make use of the truthfulness of an empty string to ensure only non-empty strings were assigned to `my_value`.

Is there a better way to perform this check?

Comment: `dict.get` doesn't assigns anything.

Comment: dict.get() does not fullfill condition #1. Two expressions are *needed*

Comment: I feel as though the title of this question is misleading. The question is specific to variable assigning, and not the branch itself.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Maybe you mean something like:

```
a.get('foo',my_default) or my_default
```

which I think should be equivalent to the `if-else` conditional you have

e.g.

```
>>> a = {'foo':''}
>>> a.get('foo','bar') or 'bar'
'bar'
>>> a['foo'] = 'baz'
>>> a.get('foo','bar') or 'bar'
'baz'
>>> a.get('qux','bar') or 'bar'
'bar'
```

The advantages to this over the other version are pretty clear.  This is nice because you only need to perform the lookup once and because `or` short circuits (As soon as it hits a `True` like value, it returns it.  If no True-like value is found, `or` returns the second one).

If your default is a function, it *could* be called twice if you write it as:  `d.get('foo',func()) or func()`.  In this case, you're better off with a temporary variable to hold the return value of `func`.

Comment: I think your second example is exactly what I'm describing. Hopefully my edit to the question clarifies this a bit. Thanks, this seems like a sensible one-line solution.

Comment: @JonathanEvans -- Now that I understand your question, I removed the first portion of my answer to avoid clutter.

Comment: @JonathanEvans there's no need to put the default value inside the call to `get`, since `get` returns `None` if unspecified which will fail the truthy test.

Comment: How is `a.get('foo',my_default) or my_default` different from `a.get('foo',my_default)` ?

Comment: Good question -- It's a corner case.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/46546872/748858

Answer (score 19):

The simplest way to do what you want:

```
my_value = dict.get(key) or my_default
```

The `or` will deliver the first value if it evaluates non-false, otherwise the second one. Unlike other languages Python doesn't force the result to be boolean, quite a useful property sometimes.

Comment: To complete your description of `or`, If both values are falsy, `or` delivers the second one -- `0 or False`

Comment: @mgilson, good observation, my description of `or` is incomplete. I'll fix it.

Comment: This answer is more elegant than the accepted one as it avoids the default value repetition.

Comment: How is this different from `dict.get(key, my_default)`?

Comment: @sam the question was very specific about using the default if the dictionary contained an empty string. Ordinarily `get` only uses the default if the key is completely *missing*.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
    try:
        post_profile = record['ownerUsername'] 

    except KeyError:
        post_profile = "nouserwasfound"
```