# What is the scenario of dict.get('..', None) or None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

if found the following code in some open source lib:

```
message.get('title', None) or None
```

is there any reason to do like this instead of `message.get('title', None)`?

Comment: The `None` in `.get(..., None)` is really redundant and superfluous.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This will guarantee that any falsy value (e.g. `None`, `''`, `0`, `False`, `[]`, ...) in the dict will turn into `None`.  i.e. if you had

```
d = {'title': False}
```

then

```
d.get('title', None)  # False
d.get('title', None) or None  # None
```

Whether there is a *practical* use-case for this is debatable, but there definitely is a subtle difference...

---

Also note that you *could* simplify this to:

```
d.get('title') or None
```

since `d.get` defaults to returning `None` if no element is found.

Comment: fwiw, a practical usecase for this is `os.environ.get('VAR') or 'some_default'` such that `$ VAR= python ...` will act equivalently to not-set.

Answer (score 1):

If you get message and it is a false-y value this will change it to None.

For example

```
message = {'title' : ''}

message.get('title', None)
>> ''

message.get('title', None) or None 
>> None
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a reason.

For example, `message.get('title', None) or None` could return an empty string. The boolean value of an empty string in Python is `False`, so `None` will be returned instead.

This would also apply to any other value returned from the `dict` that evaluates to `False`. `None` will be returned instead.

**Note:** However, that code would be better written as `message.get('title') or None`, because `dict.get` returns `None` (the second argument) by default anyways.

Comment: No, it will not return an empty string.